# mvc modal delete button not firing using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, razor, model-view-controller

I have a partialView that is used to delete a record.  I created a button to handle the deletion but I can't seem to get the button to fire the jquery.

If I add the function "deleteRecord" to the button the jquery will fire

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-id=@ViewData["id"] id="btnContinueDelete" onclick="deleteRecord(); return false;">Delete Sales Order</button>
```

However when I use an 'id' to excute the jquery the button does not fire

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-id=@ViewData["id"] id="btnContinueDelete">Delete Sales Order</button>
```

Used to excute the partialView

```
<a class="btn deleteOrder btn-danger" data-modal="" href="@Url.Action("_DeleteConfirmation", "WebOrder", new { id = @Model.Web_Order_ID, shipToName=@Model.Ship_To_Name }) role="button" data-toggle="modal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
</a>
```

Here's the PartialView

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3>Ship_To_Name</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>
        Are you sure you want to delete this Sales Order <label id="shipto-name">@ViewData["name"]</label> ID:
        <label id="data-id">@ViewData["id"]</label>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-id=@ViewData["id"] id="btnContinueDelete" onclick="writeRecord(); return false;">Delete Sales Order</button>

</div>
```

Here's the jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false, async: true });

    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm(this);
        });
        return false;
    });

    //Not working funtion
    $('#btnContinueDelete').click(function() {
        var id = $("button[data-id]").val();
        $.post(Url.Action("_DeleteConfirmation", "WebOrder"), { id: id }, function(data) {
            alert("data deleted");
        });
    });
});

// Working function
function writeRecord() {
    var id = $("button[data-id]").val();
    $.post(Url.Action("_DeleteConfirmation", "WebOrder"), { id: id }, function (data) {
        alert("data deleted");
    });
}
```

Comment: what is `bindForm(this);`

Comment: And  `var id = $("button[data-id]").val();` will always return `undefined` ( a `button` does not have a `value` attribute). It needs to be `var id = $(this).data('id');`

Comment: bindForm(this) is a function used to display the modal dialog.

Comment: thanks Stephen made that change but the button still not firing

Comment: Do you mean you not even hitting the script? Are you dynamically loading the content, in which case you need to use event delegation

Comment: sorry.. yes that is correct

Comment: I changed the function to use    $("#btnContinueDelete").on("click", function (e) {  still did not hit the jquery

Comment: @RThompson, That is not event delegation :) - See Alan Tsai's answer - it needs to be `$(someElement).on('click', '#btnContinueDelete', function() {` where `someElement` is an ancestor of `btnContinueDelete` that exists when you first render the view. (its probably `#myModalContent` but you have not shown enough detail of the view to be sure)

Answer (score 0):

Because your partial view is load in dynamic, that is why when you register the click event will not work, because by that time that id does not exist.

You will need to use `on`, such as:

```
$('#myModalContent').on('click', '#btnContinueDelete', function(event){
        var id = $("button[data-id]").val(); // remember change this
        $.post(Url.Action("_DeleteConfirmation", "WebOrder"), { id: id }, function(data) {
            alert("data deleted");
        })
});
```

for more info on the `on`, check out jquery site: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Posting is working great!  Ran into a problem.  The Url.Action is not working correctly.  Getting the following error message  http://localhost:49308/WebOrder/@Url.Action(%22_DeleteConfirmation%22,%20%22WebOrder%22)........ The code looks like this        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var url = '@Url.Action("_DeleteConfirmation", "WebOrder")';
        $.post(url, { id: id }, function (result) {
            alert('success');
        });

Comment: @RThompson were the code you show me in a javascript file? It looks like `@Url.Action("_DeleteConfirmation", "WebOrder")` was treated as string not evaluated by razor, so I am guessing the code you show me is in a javascript file.  If it is, a way to solve it is to accept the url as function parameter, and in razor use the url.action and pass it in. BTW, comment is not very good with showing code, if the above does not work, can you modify your question and show me where the code was called.